# split objects up to specific string of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data something like this

```
const data = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    id: 'id1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    id: 'id2'
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    id: 'id3'
  },
  {
    name: 'name4',
    id: 'id4'
  },
  {
    name: 'name5',
    id: 'id5'
  },
  {
    name: 'name6',
    id: 'id6'
  },
  {
    name: 'name7',
    id: 'id7'
  },
  {
    name: 'name8',
    id: 'id8'
  },

]
```

i need to push all objects up to `id3` (not include `id3`) into one array and from `id3` to `id6` (not inclue `id6`) into one array, rest of things into another array.

between `id1` and `id3` any number of objects will add but we need to push until `id3`, same way we can add number of objects into `id3` to `id6`.

finally i try to achieve like this

```
firstArr = [
   {
    name: 'name1',
    id: 'id1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    id: 'id2'
  }
]

secondArr = [
  {
    name: 'name3',
    id: 'id3'
  },
  {
    name: 'name4',
    id: 'id4'
  },
  {
    name: 'name5',
    id: 'id5'
  }
]

thirdArr = [
  {
    name: 'name6',
    id: 'id6'
  },
  {
    name: 'name7',
    id: 'id7'
  },
  {
    name: 'name8',
    id: 'id8'
  }
]
```

here the order like `id3` and `id6` won't change so that we can take this as reference.

Comment: So what's the issue? Parse your JSON, iterate over the array and add items to other arrays as required.

Comment: So `id1,id2,anyId,anotherId,id3,id4,something,id6,id7` should be split this way: `id1,id2 | anyId,anotherId,id3,id4,something | id6,id7` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Array.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```
const id3Index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 'id3');
const id6Index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 'id6');
const arr1 = data.slice(0, id3Index);
const arr2 = data.slice(id3Index, id6Index);
const arr3 = data.slice(id6Index);
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    id: 'id1'
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    id: 'id2'
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    id: 'id3'
  },
  {
    name: 'name4',
    id: 'id4'
  },
  {
    name: 'name5',
    id: 'id5'
  },
  {
    name: 'name6',
    id: 'id6'
  },
  {
    name: 'name7',
    id: 'id7'
  },
  {
    name: 'name8',
    id: 'id8'
  },

]

const id3Index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 'id3');
const id6Index = data.findIndex(obj => obj.id === 'id6');
console.log(data.slice(0, id3Index));
console.log(data.slice(id3Index, id6Index));
console.log(data.slice(id6Index));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and then use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

I think its not good idea to make variables like `firstArr,...` instead you can create array of arrays

```js
const data = [ { name: 'name1', id: 'id1' }, { name: 'name2', id: 'id2' }, { name: 'name3', id: 'id3' }, { name: 'name4', id: 'id4' }, { name: 'name5', id: 'id5' }, { name: 'name6', id: 'id6' }, { name: 'name7', id: 'id7' }, { name: 'name8', id: 'id8' }, ]


function split(data,...strs){
  let res = [];
  let last = 0;
  strs.forEach((x,i) => {
    let index = data.findIndex(a => a.id === x);
    res.push(data.slice(last,index));
    last = index;
  })
  return res.concat([data.slice(last)])
}

let result = split(data,"id3","id6")

const [first,second,third] = result;


console.log('First:',first);
console.log('Second:',second);
console.log('Third:',third);
```

If you want to do that on basis of `id` You can use `findIndex` and then `slice()`

Comment: @Urock Why don’t you iterate over the array and find the index of Id1 and id3 and then splice it?

Comment: It's not fixed response and it what if i add some objects between id1 and id2

Comment: @Andreas, I’m sorry I tagged you bymistkenly.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'name1', id: 'id1' },
    { name: 'name2', id: 'id2' },
    { name: 'name3', id: 'id3' },
    { name: 'name4', id: 'id4' },
    { name: 'name5', id: 'id5' },
    { name: 'name6', id: 'id6' },
    { name: 'name7', id: 'id7' },
    { name: 'name8', id: 'id8' },
];

const firstArr = [];
const secondArr = [];
const thirdArr = [];

data.map(item => {
    if (item.id < 'id3') {
        firstArr.push(item);
    } else if (item.id > 'id5') {
        thirdArr.push(item);
    } else {
        secondArr.push(item);
    }
});

console.log(firstArr);
console.log(secondArr);
console.log(thirdArr);
```

Comment: That is not what `map` is for. `map` is when you want to create a new array using the data from the original. In this case, you're splitting it into 3 new arrays, so you really should be using `forEach` instead.

Comment: Change `id4` to `id14` and test your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to locate `id3` and `id6` and then use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and to extract the sub-arrays:

```js
const data = [{name:"name1",id:"id1"},{name:"name2",id:"id2"},{name:"name3",id:"id3"},{name:"name4",id:"id4"},{name:"name5",id:"id5"},{name:"name6",id:"id6"},{name:"name7",id:"id7"},{name:"name8",id:"id8"}];

function process(arr) {
  const id3 = arr.findIndex(({ id }) => id === 'id3');
  const id6 = arr.findIndex(({ id }) => id === 'id6');
  return [arr.slice(0, id3), arr.slice(id3, id6), arr.slice(id6)];
}

const [arr1, arr2, arr3] = process(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a reducer function like this

```js
console.clear()
const data = [
  {name: "name1", id: "id1"},
  {name: "name2", id: "id2"},
  {name: "name3", id: "id3"},
  {name: "name4", id: "id4"},
  {name: "name5", id: "id5"},
  {name: "name6", id: "id6"},
  {name: "name7", id: "id7"},
  {name: "name8", id: "id8"}
];


// start and end are arrays, which contain triggers
// start will activate, end
// id is the key to check, defaults to 'id'
const reducerId = (activate, deactivate, key) => {
  key = key || 'id'
  let use = false
  return (item, index) => {
    if (activate.length === 0 && index === 0 || activate.includes(item[key])) {
      use = true
    }
    if (deactivate.includes(item[key])) {
      use = false
    }
    return use;
  }
}

// arr is the array to split
// use is a callback, which must return true or false, depending on whether the 
// currentItem should be used in the accumulated result array or not
const splitId = (arr, use) => {
  let found = false;
  return arr.reduce((accu, item, index, source) => {
    if (use(item, index)) {
      accu.push(item)
    }
    return accu
  }, [])
}


const first = splitId(data, reducerId([], ['id3']));
const second = splitId(data, reducerId(['id3'], ['id6']));
const third = splitId(data, reducerId(['id6'], []));
console.log(JSON.stringify(first))
console.log(JSON.stringify(second))
console.log(JSON.stringify(third))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`

- Here idea is first sort id's
- Now loop through sorted data and as soon as you find any matching id push it to final output and remove that element from `range` and `reset temp`

```js
const data = [{ name: 'name1', id: 'id1' },{ name: 'name2', id: 'id2' },{ name: 'name3', id: 'id3' },{ name: 'name4', id: 'id4' },{ name: 'name5', id: 'id5' },{ name: 'name6', id: 'id6' },{ name: 'name7', id: 'id7' },{ name: 'name8', id: 'id8' },];

let range = ['id3','id6','id9']
let temp = []
let op = data.sort(({id:a,id:b}) => a.localeCompare(b)).reduce((op,inp)=>{
  temp.push(inp)
  if(inp.id === range[0]){
    op.push(temp)
    temp = []
    range.shift()
  }
  return op
},[])
if(temp.length){
  op.push(temp)
}
console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array for the `id` values and take a new array if you got a know `id`.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'name1', id: 'id1' }, { name: 'name2', id: 'id2' }, { name: 'name3', id: 'id3' }, { name: 'name4', id: 'id4' }, { name: 'name5', id: 'id5' }, { name: 'name6', id: 'id6' }, { name: 'name7', id: 'id7' }, { name: 'name8', id: 'id8' }],
    groups = ['id3', 'id6'],
    [one, two, three] = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (o.id === groups[0]) {
            r.push([]);
            groups.shift();
        }
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, [[]]);

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```